# How to control equation labelling in "align" environment?

Tags: equations, numbering, align

I would like to write something of the form:

```
\begin{align}  
c_1 & = 1 \\  
c_2 & = 1 + 2 \\  
c_3 & = 1 + 2 + 3  \\  
& \; \; \vdots  
\end{align}
```

I would like the first three equations to have "normal" equation numbering, but the last line involving `\vdots` to be *without* equation numbering. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are loading `amsmath`, you can use `\notag` (without `amsmath` there's `\nonumber`) to suppress the numbering for a given line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} 

\begin{align}
c_1 &= 1 \\
c_2 &= 1 + 2 \\
c_3 &= 1 + 2 + 3 \\
&\;\;\vdots \notag
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I actually use `align` as well so I edited it (I do not know why I typed `aligned`).

Comment: @Hunter You're welcome! I edited my answer; adding that with amsmath, you can also use `\notag`.